# SSLHandshakeException and CertificateException on SQL connection creating

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I was jst started learning SQL and trying to use JDBC create connection with mysql, but everytime I try to build connection this exception prompt up. I'm pretty sure I wrote url right and I can open up it in sqlyog, I'm not so sure what's the problem. How should I solve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,457 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,451 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:202)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at jdbc.main(jdbc.java:9)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1640)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:187)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:303)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1099)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1622)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:159)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:85)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:296)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: And after I change useSSL to false, there is no exception. But what actually is this useSSL stands for?

Comment: useSSL means that the communication uses Secure Sockets Layer. it secures the communication. But I think that you need to specify a certification for that I'm not sure. You will find plenty of tutorials on web on how to use ssl to do jdbc communication in java